Autograd error caused by ReLU in Pytorch?
I am using a residual neural network for a classification task. Somehow adding or omitting a ReLU activation causes the autograd to fail. I would be grateful for any insights on the reason for this? It cannot make any sense of it. ReLU is not an inplace operation, is it? Error message:
RuntimeError: one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operation
Here is the network architecture. The 3rd to last line is what causes the issue when not commented out.
class ResidualBlock(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_filters, kernel_size):
        super(ResidualBlock, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv1d(num_filters, num_filters, kernel_size=kernel_size, padding='same')
        self.bn1 = nn.BatchNorm1d(num_filters)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv1d(num_filters, num_filters, kernel_size=kernel_size, padding='same')
        self.bn2 = nn.BatchNorm1d(num_filters)

    def forward(self, x):
        shortcut = x
        out = F.relu(self.bn1(self.conv1(x)))
        out = self.bn2(self.conv2(out))
        out = F.relu(out) # causes the issue when not commented out
        out += shortcut
        return out

Below is a minimal working example. I am using Python 3.12 and torch 2.5.1.
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, TensorDataset

# Define the ResidualBlock
class ResidualBlock(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_filters, kernel_size):
        super(ResidualBlock, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv1d(num_filters, num_filters, kernel_size=kernel_size, padding='same')
        self.bn1 = nn.BatchNorm1d(num_filters)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv1d(num_filters, num_filters, kernel_size=kernel_size, padding='same')
        self.bn2 = nn.BatchNorm1d(num_filters)

    def forward(self, x):
        shortcut = x
        out = F.relu(self.bn1(self.conv1(x)))
        out = self.bn2(self.conv2(out))
        out = F.relu(out) # causes the issue
        out += shortcut
        return out


class SimpleModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_filters, kernel_size):
        super(SimpleModel, self).__init__()
        self.res_block = ResidualBlock(num_filters, kernel_size)
        self.fc = nn.Linear(num_filters, 1)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.res_block(x)
        x = x.mean(dim=2)
        x = self.fc(x)
        return x

torch.manual_seed(42)
num_samples = 1000
sequence_length = 32
num_filters = 16

X = torch.randn(num_samples, num_filters, sequence_length)  # Random input
y = torch.sum(X, dim=(1, 2), keepdim=True)  # Simple target (sum of all values)


dataset = TensorDataset(X, y)
dataloader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=32, shuffle=True)


model = SimpleModel(num_filters=num_filters, kernel_size=3)
criterion = nn.MSELoss() 
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)


epochs = 5
for epoch in range(epochs):
    model.train()
    epoch_loss = 0.0
    for batch_X, batch_y in dataloader:
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        outputs = model(batch_X)
        loss = criterion(outputs, batch_y)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        epoch_loss += loss.item()
    print(f"Epoch {epoch+1}/{epochs}, Loss: {epoch_loss/len(dataloader):.4f}")

print("Training complete!")


The inplace operation is this:
out += shortcut

The relu needs its own output to compute its gradient! Thus you are doing an inplace operation on the output of the relu, which it needed to compute its gradient in the backwards pass.
replacing it with
out = out + shortcut

should solve your problem.
In general, try to avoid using inplace functions in pytorch (such as += unless you know what you are doing

more details:
if you look at the pytorch code, the backwards pass for the relu is auto-generated from the following bit of code in pytorch/tools/autograd/derivatives.yaml
- name: relu(Tensor self) -> Tensor
  self: threshold_backward(grad, result, 0)
  result: auto_element_wise

What this does is it

takes the gradient of the output as grad
and the result of the relu as result
and returns the contents of grad where result is bigger than 0 and 0 otherwise.

Thus it does need the output (technically, it could have stored its input instead, but this is how it is implemented)
